# Unique classes in a nested list

Tags: r, list, nested

I am looking for a straight forward way to get the unique classes of the first-level elements in a nested list.

Reproducible example:

```
x = list(list(1,"A"), # Unique classes:  character, numeric
         4, # Unique classes: numeric
         list(1,2,list(4,5, list(6)))) # Unique classes: numeric

# Expected return: list(c('character', 'numeric'), c('numeric'), c('numeric'))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works

```
list_classes <- function(ls) {
  unique(sapply(ls, class))
}

lapply(x, list_classes)

#[[1]]
#[1] "numeric"   "character"

#[[2]]
#[1] "numeric"

#[[3]]
#[1] "numeric" "list"
```

**Edit:** Recursive version

```
list_classes <- function(ls) {

  # get classes of list
  cls <- sapply(ls, class)

  # which are lists themselves
  which_ls <- cls == "list"
  lists <- ls[which_ls]

  # which are non lists
  non_lists <- cls[!which_ls]

  # recursively evaluate contents of list for their classes
  return(
    unique(
      c(non_lists, sapply(lists, list_classes), recursive = T)
    )
  )

}

lapply(x, list_classes)


#[[1]]
#[1] "numeric"   "character"

#[[2]]
#[1] "numeric"

#[[3]]
#[1] "numeric"
```

Comment: Still not identical to the desired output.

Comment: True, I've just realised, need to unpack some lists

Comment: @BonStats A work around would be to make your function recursive.

Comment: @agenis `list_classes()` applies the `class()` function onto each element of the list `ls` and returns the class of each element as a simple vector. The `unique()` function removes duplicate classes. 

Is this the desired output or should the final class listed be "numeric" instead of "list"?

Comment: You could replace the inside loop with `rapply` -- something like `lapply(rapply(x, class, how = "replace"), function(X) unique(unlist(X)))` seems to work.

Comment: @m0h3n added a recursive version as suggested.
@alexis_laz thank you for pointing out `rapply` I'll need to look into that

Comment: using @alexis_laz idea, i can suggest also in one line: `x %>% lapply(list) %>% lapply(function(y) y %>% rapply(class) %>% unique)`